# Roundcube condition on screen size

Tags: responsive-design, xhtml, conditional-statements, viewport, roundcube

I'm asking this because I have not been able to find the answer anywhere.

I am using Roundcube to build a web mail application. Roundcube has custom XHTML-tags that can be used to display things, together with normal HTML. These XHTML-tags can have an attribute "`condition`" which, if I understand correctly, will only display the element if the condition is fullfilled. Examples:

```
<roundcube:if condition="var &lt; 0" />
    <div> ... </div>
<roundcube:elseif condition="var &gt; 0" />
    <span> ... </span>
<roundcube:else />
    <p> ... </p>
<roundcube:endif />

<roundcube:container name="container-desktop" id="container-desktop" condition="!myCondition" />
<roundcube:container name="container-mobile" id="container-mobile" condition="myCondition" />
```

My problem is that I would like to change the condition dewpending on the screen/viewport width. Basically depending on if the user is usnig mobile, tablet or desktop. What I want to do is show a div if the user is on mobile or tablet, but not on desktop, or the other way around.

I have not been able to find this in any way. Is there someone who knows hos this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a goto person for Roundcube, so maybe someone else can help you find a Roundcube @media conditional tag.

As an alternative though, have you considered solving this with off-the-shelf HTML and CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-desktop">
    <!-- desktop content -->
</div>

<div class="container-mobile">
    <!-- mobile content -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>...</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* mobile first ==> by default show mobile view */
        .container-desktop{display: none;}

        /* show desktop view for viewports above 480px, adjust as required */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 481px){
           .container-desktop{display: block;}
           .container-mobile{display: none;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if the content of `.container-desktop` will be loaded at all on the mobile view?

It is very important that the desktop content is not loaded in any way in the mobile view and the other way around. It has to do with advertising, revenue and SEO.

Comment: With the above, the content in the desktop container would be loaded but not displayed on mobile, and the opposite on desktop. So maybe this isn't the perfect solution in this case ;)

Comment: That was what I was afraid of and what it looked like when I tried myself.

The problem with ads is that you get less revenue if the ad is loaded but not displayed. That is why sites usually always use lazy loading for ads.